# install latest xgboost nightly build

Tags: python, installation, xgboost

I'd like to install the latest xgboost nightly build. The documentation indicates that the latest builds can be found here: https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/xgboost-nightly-builds/list.html?prefix=master/

Getting the name of the latest version you can then use pip in the following maner (exemple):

```
!pip install https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/xgboost-nightly-builds/master/xgboost-2.0.0.dev0%2B15ca12a77ebbaf76515291064c24d8c2268400fd-py3-none-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl
```

Is there any way to just specify 'latest nightly build' some way or another instead of having to copy past the commit key ?

Comment: In the provided link, the current latest nightly build is `xgboost-2.1.0.dev0+1b87a1d8f8c1b372f1101badc7b3fdf03499ea28-py3-none-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl`. Is that what you want to install? If yes, you can write your own web scraping code to extract the latest wheel and use subprocess to install it. Every time you want latest wheel, run this custom script.

Comment: Well this is exactly my point. It is changing almost everyday. I was wondering if there is a standalone approach instead of having to scrape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the page source, it is evident that the list of nightly builds is dynamically populated using JavaScript. To scrape content populated by JavaScript, you can use Selenium or any other headless browser approach that executes the JavaScript code to generate the full DOM.

First, install Selenium and a compatible WebDriver, such as the Chrome WebDriver.

```bash
pip install selenium
```

Download the correct version of ChromeDriver from [here](https://sites.google.com/chromium.org/driver/?pli=1) and make it accessible in your system's `PATH`.

The code would then attempt to fetch the most recent `.whl` file specifically built for `manylinux2014_x86_64` and install it.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
import subprocess
import time

# Initialize WebDriver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

# Open the URL
driver.get("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/xgboost-nightly-builds/list.html?prefix=master/")

# Wait for the list to load
try:
    element_present = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'listing'))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(element_present)
except TimeoutException:
    print("Timed out waiting for page to load")

time.sleep(5)  # Further delay to ensure JavaScript has time to load

# Extract the URLs
links = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'a')

# Initialize a variable to store the latest build URL
latest_build_url = ""

# Iterate through links in reverse to find the most recent one that matches our criteria
for link in reversed([l.get_attribute('href') for l in links]):
    if "py3-none-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl" in link:
        latest_build_url = link
        break

# Close the browser
driver.close()

# Install the latest build using pip
if latest_build_url:
    subprocess.run(["pip", "install", latest_build_url])
else:
    print("Latest build not found.")
```

Note: The WebDriver will wait for a maximum of 10 seconds for the list to load. Adjust this value as needed.

That approach should allow you to fetch the list of URLs after the JavaScript has populated them. Please be aware that this method also relies on the current structure of the page, which could change.

---

If you find Selenium to be overkill, another lighter option is to use Python's [`playwright`](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright-python), a Python library to automate Chromium, Firefox and WebKit browsers with a single API. It replaces [`pyppeteer`](https://github.com/pyppeteer/pyppeteer).

```bash
pip install playwright
playwright install
```

Here is a sample script:

```py
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright
import subprocess

with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.launch()
    page = browser.new_page()
    page.goto('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/xgboost-nightly-builds/list.html?prefix=master/')
    page.wait_for_selector('#listing')
    
    # Assume the list is sorted by the most recent; adjust if necessary
    link_element = page.query_selector('a[href*="py3-none-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl"]')
    latest_build_url = link_element.get_attribute("href")
    
    browser.close()

    if latest_build_url:
        subprocess.run(["pip", "install", latest_build_url])
    else:
        print("Latest build not found.")
```

That would be lighter than using Selenium and should handle the JavaScript-loaded content. It will launch a headless browser, navigate to the page, wait for the listing to load, and then retrieve and install the latest build.

Comment: Thanks. It seems a bit overkill though.

Comment: @lcrmorin OK, I have edited the answer to provide a simpler alternative.

Answer (score -1):

If is the naigtly version loaded on pip ten you can install trough pip. In case is isn't loaded in pip then no.

Comment: how would one do that ? I am genuinely interested but not sure how to do it (automatically) from your answer. Is there a pip answer or something ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this may be a start to the answer to the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some **more explanation**.